# Hyperledger fabric composer test sample not work?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I follow and try same sample code in this instruction
[Playground tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/playground-guide.html)

but when I submit a transaction `Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.acme.mynetwork.Trade#d77dbd2d-53e3-4435-b4fb-d802d5bd6bec`.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: did you mean step 11 ? Did  you perform steps 5 through 7 to update the model and transaction logic and update the business network?

Comment: yes, I got this error when perform step 11. I already performed steps 5 through 7 and updated network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been an error you saw in Playground in v0.14.3. Suggest to update (ie re-install) your Composer dev environment to the current release v0.15.0 (as of Nov 10th) - there is a new tutorial (its changed from what you saw) and it will use Business network cards for the network deploy (createComposerProfile.sh is no longer needed) - makes life easier.  To get the latest version, you will need to install the modules as per the docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html - this will get the latest release. Make sure you do a full teardown using the scripts you downloaded in fabric-tools (as your CC containers will be 0.14.3 or earlier and thus out of date) and that you then subsequently, do an npm -g uninstall of the same module names eg composer-cli, composer-playground etc and such that they are all at the same level (0.15.0) upon subsequent npm -g install of same composer modules.